# How to select all the Input at once from selectInput function in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, selectinput

In the shiny App which I am creating I have a set of Drop down list boxes which are interconnected with each other. That is the input of One drop down box decides the set of Input for others.

For the drop down boxes i use selectInput() function to do it and also there are drop down boxes from which I need to select multiple options.

But when the number of options are more the user is required to select each and every option individually. Is there any way to select all the options at once.

That is kind of having a "ALL" option. which selects everything.

I don't want to use `"pickerInput"`function please.

As my options in the drop down are dependent on the previous drop down input, I am not able to create a static choices list.

As a work around i used a checker box input to select all the values in the drop down list, but Unfortunately its not working.

Kindly find the UI and Server code below.

```
Source_Data <-
data.frame(
key = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
Product_Name = c(
  "Table",
  "Table",
  "Chair",
  "Table",
  "Bed",
  "Bed",
  "Sofa",
  "Chair",
  "Sofa"
),
Product_desc = c("XX", "XX", "YY", "XX", "Z", "ZZZ", "A", "Y", "AA"),
Cost = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
)
```

The UI and the server code

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Demo"),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput(
                  "key",
                  "keys",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 3,
                  value = c(1, 3),
                  step = 1
                ),
                selectInput("Product", "List of Products", choices = NULL),
                selectInput(
                  "Product_d",
                  "Product Description",
                  choices = NULL,
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  selected = TRUE
                ),
                checkboxInput('all', 'Select All/None'),
                actionButton("Button", "ok")
              ),
              mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("table_data", DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
              ))

            ))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
observeEvent(input$key, {
updateSelectInput(
  session,
  "Product",
  "List of Products",
  choices = unique(
    Source_Data %>% filter(key %in% input$key) %>% select
    (Product_Name)
  )
)
})

observeEvent(c(input$key, input$Product, input$all), {
updateSelectInput(
  session,
  "Product_d",
  "Product Description",
  choices = unique(
    Source_Data %>% filter(key %in% input$key,
                           Product_Name %in% input$Product) %>% select
    (Product_desc)
  ),
  selected = if (input$all)
    unique(
      Source_Data %>% filter(key %in% input$key,
                             Product_Name %in% input$Product) %>% select
      (Product_desc)

    )

}))

output_func <- eventReactive(input$Button, {
key_input <- input$key
Product_input <- input$Product
Product_desc_input <- input$Product_d
cat_input <- input$Product_desc
div_input <- input$divisions

z <-
  Source_Data %>% dplyr::arrange (key) %>% dplyr::select(key,
                                                         Product_Name,
                                                         Product_Desc,
                                                         Cost) %>% 
dplyr::filter (
                                                           key %inrange% 
key_input,
                                                           Product_Name == 
Product_input,
                                                           Product_Desc == 
Product_desc_input
                                                         )

return(z)
})

output$table_data <-
DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(output_func())
})
}
```

Any suggestions would help please.

Thanks in advance

David

Comment: There is an option to select all / deselect all items in pickerInput from the shinyWidgets package.

Comment: @laurenzo Thanks for the comment :) Actually I dont want to use it its changing the formatting of the Dashboard.

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that when I read your question at first.

Comment: No Problem All good  :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to select all items by clicking a button:

```
library(shiny)

js1 <- paste0(c(
  "Selectize.prototype.selectall = function(){",
  "  var self = this;",
  "  self.setValue(Object.keys(self.options));",
  "}"), 
  collapse = "\n")

js2 <- paste0(c(
  "var selectinput = document.getElementById('select');",
  "selectinput.selectize.setValue(-1, false);",
  "selectinput.selectize.selectall();",
  "$('#select + .selectize-control .item').removeClass('active');"),
  collapse = "\n")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(js1)),
  actionButton("selectall", "Select all", onclick = js2),
  br(),
  selectizeInput("select", "Select", choices = month.name, multiple = TRUE, 
                 options = list(
                   plugins = list("remove_button")
                 )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Answer :) It has provided me a new way to think. Actually I tried the code but one issue which I am facing is I am not sure on what changes i should do in my Server(). Also I have the select inputs in which the options/choices in top drop down will decide the choices in next drop downs. So I wont be able to mention my choices in the UI. Can you please suggest me on how to overcome this . Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like 'All products' to your vector of choices, and then generate the secondary `selectizeInput` with `renderUI` by filtering your dataframe. (I've also converted your df to characters so that `unique()` works properly.)

```
df <- Source_Data %>% mutate_all(as.character)

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        selectizeInput('product_name', 'Product name', choices = c('All products', unique(df$Product_Name)), selected = 'All products', multiple = TRUE),
        uiOutput('secondary_select')
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$secondary_select <- renderUI({
        if ('All products' %in% input$product_name) {
            prod_desc <- unique(df$Product_desc)
        } else {
            df <- df %>% filter(Product_Name == input$product_name)
            prod_desc <- unique(df$Product_desc)
        }
        selectizeInput('product_desc', 'Product description', choices = c('All descriptions', prod_desc))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```